# Non embedded curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

What does it mean to say that a curve in $\mathbb{ R}^3$ is non-embedded ?

I think if it's lies on a plane , but i cant find any book who give this definition or some examples

thank you for your help

Comment: Well, if you have the definition of embedded curve in $\mathbb R^3$, then a curve is non-embedded if .... it is not embedded.

Comment: I cant find the defintion of embedded curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Wiki page has it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#Differential_topology).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a figure-8, it can be drawn smoothly, you get an *immersion* of the circle, but not an *embedding*; an embedding is required to be 1-to-1, but the lemniscate has a "crossing" in the middle.

Here's a parametric version; you can defined it for $0 \le t \le 2 \pi$, for instance:
$$
x = \frac{\cos t}{1+\sin^2 t} \\
y = \frac{\sin t \cos t}{1+\sin^2 t} 
$$

An embedding it also required to be *smooth*, so that 
$$
t \mapsto (t, t^\frac{1}{3}, 0)
$$
for instance, is not an embedding, although the image of that map is indeed *also* the image of an embedding, so you can't always tell that a map is a non-embedding by merely looking at its image. Finally, there are cases where looking at the image is enough, like
$$
t \mapsto (t, t^\frac{2}{3}, 0).
$$

This curve, at $t = 0$, has a "cusp", and no amount of reparameterizing will make it smooth.